# Apollo Angular returning empty data, while Postman request returns correct data with same query

Tags: angular, graphql, apollo

I am currently having problems with the Apollo Angular Client, as when I introduce some query to get the results from my graphql endpoint it will return a 200 response but returning empty data.

this is the code I'm using to fetch the data.

```
  const query = gql`
  { 
    KPI (label: "RejectionRatio") {
        definedIn sourceField computedBy series {
            fromDate toDate value

        }

    } 

}
  `;

  return this.apollo.query({query}).pipe(
    tap(v => console.log('v',v)),
    map(result => result.data),
  );
}
```

This are the request payload. I don't know if the typenames are added automatically but it's the only difference I can find.

```
{
    "operationName":null,
    "variables":{},
    "query":"{
        KPI(label: \"RejectionRatio\") {
            definedIn
            sourceField
            computedBy
            series {
                fromDate
                toDate
                value
                __typename
            }
            __typename
        }
    }
}
```

And the response.

[response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WP185.png)

```
{"data":[]}
```

The interesting thing is that when i try to do it in postman using the same endpoint and selecting GraphQL as the body type, I am getting the correct data. I append an image of the whole page so you can see it.

`{"data":[{"definedIn":"Number of claims rejected within 24h","sourceField":["Claim Rejected Date","Claim Identifier","Claim Status"],"computedBy":"n(claim rejected date OR claim status is rejected)/n(claims with identifier)","series":[{"fromDate":"2019-10-01","toDate":"2019-10-02","value":"3"},{"fromDate":"2019-10-07","toDate":"2019-10-08","value":"3"},{"fromDate":"2019-10-06","toDate":"2019-10-07","value":"4"},{"fromDate":"2019-10-03","toDate":"2019-10-04","value":"5"},{"fromDate":"2019-10-15","toDate":"2019-10-16","value":"4"},{"fromDate":"2019-10-09","toDate":"2019-10-10","value":"1"},{"fromDate":"2019-10-08","toDate":"2019-10-09","value":"4"},{"fromDate":"2019-10-12","toDate":"2019-10-13","value":"2"},{"fromDate":"2019-10-10","toDate":"2019-10-11","value":"2"},{"fromDate":"2019-10-04","toDate":"2019-10-05","value":"5"},{"fromDate":"2019-10-13","toDate":"2019-10-14","value":"3"},{"fromDate":"2019-10-14","toDate":"2019-10-15","value":"3"},{"fromDate":"2019-10-05","toDate":"2019-10-06","value":"3"},{"fromDate":"2019-10-02","toDate":"2019-10-03","value":"4"},{"fromDate":"2019-10-11","toDate":"2019-10-12","value":"5"}]}]}`

[Payload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQ85Y.png)

Thanks for everything in advance.
Kind Regards.
Javier

Comment: Are there headers or cookies that, if missing, could cause the `KPI` resolver to return an empty array?